# image getting saves as text in android app

Tags: php

Hi i am trying to upload images form my app and want same to be saved in my web folder I've used the php code as mentioned below however file is getting saved as txt , however i would need jpeg file for my future use.

PHP code -

```
<?php  
// Get image string posted from Android App  
 $base=$_REQUEST['image'];  
  // Get file name posted from Android App  
  $filename = $_REQUEST['name'];  
  // Decode Image  
 $binary=base64_decode($base);  
 header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');  
  // Images will be saved under 'www/domain.com/images' folder  
 $file = fopen('images/'.$filename, 'wb');  
  // Create File  
  fwrite($file, $binary,);  
 fclose($file);  
 echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code when you post your image from the app

```
try {
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(image1);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(myUri));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            image = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


       List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, Following code helps you to store the image on server using PHP. I am assuming that you are getting image name in post parameter.

```
$binary = base64_decode($image);
$filename = $_REQUEST['name'];  
file_put_contents('images/'.$filename, $binary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive done it from my side it self though thanks for your support guys .

```
  <?php  
// Get image string posted from Android App  
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];  
// Get file name posted from Android App  
$filename = $_REQUEST['name'].'.jpg';  
// Decode Image  
$binary=base64_decode($base);  
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');  
// Images will be saved under 'www/domain.com/images' folder  
$file = fopen('images/'.$filename, 'wb');  
 // Create File  
 fwrite($file, $binary,);  
fclose($file);  
echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';  
?>
```